# SendGrid Webhook Event Custom Headers

Tags: webhooks, sendgrid

While sending an email through SendGrid I am sending custom headers. I have an Function App listening to Webhook events from SendGrid. But I am not getting those custom headers back in the WebHook events. Is there a way to configure the webhooks to get the custom headers back from SendGrid ?

```
var client = new SendGridClient("API_KEY");
var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
var subject = "Testing with SendGrid API";
var to = new EmailAddress("joe@test.com", "Example User");
var plainTextContent = "Test Content";
var htmlContent = "<strong>Testing with HTML content</strong>";
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
var identifiers = new Dictionary<String, String>();
identifiers["application"] = "APP_NAME_GOES_HERE";
identifiers["resource"] = "RESOURCE_NAME_GOES_HERE";    
 msg.AddHeaders(identifiers);   
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

When you are using the API to send emails, the best way to get properties sent back in the webhook is using custom arguments (`custom_args`).

You can add them to this code, by replacing `AddHeaders` with `addCustomArgs` like so:

```cs
var identifiers = new Dictionary<String, String>();
identifiers["application"] = "APP_NAME_GOES_HERE";
identifiers["resource"] = "RESOURCE_NAME_GOES_HERE";    
msg.addCustomArgs(identifiers);
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

See the [examples in the tests](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/tests/SendGrid.Tests/Integration.cs#L1905-L1914) for more.