# Custom headers on sendgrid webhook

Tags: java, http-headers, arguments, twilio, sendgrid

I have a spring boot application that sends request to SendGrid client to send email out.
And I also have an API configured successfully in sendgrid webhook settings and able to get updates back from sendgrid.
Now requirement is, We need to get some custom headers back from sendgrid when my application receives updates back from sendgrid through webhook.
After seeing this question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68069911/sendgrid-webhook-event-custom-headers), I understood I need to add customArguments.

Mail request logic as shown below:

```
Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
mail.addCustomArg("Key", "123456789");
mail.addCustomArg("version", "v6.5.8");
Request request = new Request();
request.setMethod(Method.POST);
request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
request.setBody(mail.build());

log.trace("Making request to SendGrid using api-key: {}", apiKey);
SendGrid sendGrid = new SendGrid(apiKey);
Response response = sendGrid.api(request);
```

And in sendgrid ActivityFeed, when I looked at the email that I sent through to sendgrid. I can see the headers information as well(Key, version).

But they are not coming back through webhook update. I have added `@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers` so I can catch all the headers. But I dont see key and version in the headers.
May I know what am I missing here.